# Impact on SQL 2000 performance of JDBC selectMethod=cursor

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

([Posted first on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622500/), but its not getting any answers there. Cross-posting to reach a larger audience, since it is cross-discipline.)

In the process of trying to help out an app dev team with some performance issues on a SQL 2000 server, I ran a SQL trace and discovered that all calls to the database are full of API Server Cursor statements (sp_cursorprepexec, sp_cursorfetch, sp_cursorclose).

Looks like they're specifying some connection string properties that force the use of server-side cursors, retrieving only 128 rows of data at a time: (From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa172588)

> When the API cursor attributes or
>   properties are set to anything other
>   than their defaults, the OLE DB
>   provider for SQL Server and the SQL
>   Server ODBC driver use API server
>   cursors instead of default result
>   sets. Each call to an API function
>   that fetches rows generates a
>   roundtrip to the server to fetch the
>   rows from the API server cursor.

**UPDATE**: They have multiple Java apps using a JDBC connection to the SQL server with `selectMethod=cursor` specified (as opposed to `selectMethod=direct`).

From my DBA perspective, that's just annoying (it clutters the trace up with useless junk), and in all likelihood is resulting in many extra app-to-SQL server round trips, reducing overall performance.

They've apparently tested `selectMethod=direct` in a very limited way (changed just one application out of ~60) and experienced some issues of some sort (technical details of which I do not have).

So, my questions are:

- What's the performance impact of `selectMethod=cursor` vs `direct` on an already busy SQL 2000 server? (I had speculated that increasing the number of round trips between SQL and APP servers can't do anything good. Was I wrong?)
- Is `selectMethod` an application-transparent setting? Could this break their apps if we change it?
- When should they use `cursor` vs `direct`? Are there some types of apps that would benefit from one over the other?

**Update**: Found out the name of the driver parameter, which have warranted significant edits to title, body, and tags.

**Update**: Added bounty. Also added bounty to SO question (which is more focused on application behavior). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly,

1. `selectMethod=cursor`

   - theoretically requires [more server-side resources](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/cursors_p1.aspx) than `selectMethod=direct`
   - only loads at most *batch-size* records into client memory at once, resulting in a more predictable client memory footprint
2. `selectMethod=direct`

   - theoretically requires less server-side resources than `selectMethod=cursor`
   - will read the entire result set into client memory (unless the driver natively supports asynchronous result set retrieval) before the client application can iterate over it; this **can reduce performance in two ways**:

     1. reduced performance with large result sets if the client application is written in such a way as to stop processing after traversing only a fraction of the result set (with `direct` it has already paid the cost of retrieving data it will essentially throw away; with `cursor` the waste is limited to at most *batch-size* - 1 rows -- the early termination condition should probably be recoded in SQL anyway e.g. as `SELECT TOP` or window functions)
     2. reduced performance with large result sets because of potential garbage collection and/or out-of-memory issues associated with an increased memory footprint

In summary,

- *Can using `selectMethod=cursor` lower application performance?* -- either method can lower performance, for different reasons.  Past a certain resultset size, `cursor` may still be preferable.  See below for when to use one or the other
- *Is `selectMethod=` an application-transparent setting on a JDBC connection?* -- it is transparent, but it can still break their app if memory usage grows significantly enough to hog their client system (and, correspondingly, your server) or crash the client altogether
- *More generally, when should you use `cursor` vs `direct`?* -- I personally use `cursor` when dealing with potentially large or otherwise unbounded result sets.  The roundtrip overhead is then amortized given a large enough batch size, and my client memory footprint is predictable.  I use `direct` when the size of the result set I expect is known to be inferior to whatever batch size I use with `cursor`, or bound in some way, or when memory is not an issue.

Cheers,
V.